# Passing Json data according to the json file Id in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I have a problem and I've tried many times and I didn't succeed please want you to help me! I have a RecyclerView where I'm getting data from json files. I have two jsons file and my json files looks like that:

```
{ "ussd_code":[
{"cmd_id": 1,"cmd_name": "Solde de crédit","cmd_instruction": "*100#","cmd_commentaire": null,"opetor_id": 2,"mnu_id": 12,"test":2},
{"cmd_id": 2,"cmd_name": "Solde de crédit","cmd_instruction": "*565#","cmd_commentaire": null,"opetor_id": 1,"mnu_id": 12,"test":1},
{"cmd_id": 3,"cmd_name": "Solde de crédit","cmd_instruction": "*124#","cmd_commentaire": null,"opetor_id": 3,"mnu_id": 12,"test":3},
{"cmd_id": 4,"cmd_name": "Airtel Money","cmd_instruction": "*501#","cmd_commentaire": null,"opetor_id": 1,"mnu_id": 12,"test":1},
{"cmd_id": 5,"cmd_name": "Mon numéro","cmd_instruction": "*502#","cmd_commentaire": null,"opetor_id": 1,"mnu_id": 12,"test":1},
{"cmd_id": 6,"cmd_name": "8 minutes (Vers airtel)","cmd_instruction": "*171*50#", "cmd_commentaire": "50 Unités pour 1 jour","opetor_id": 1,"mnu_id": 11,"test":1},
{"cmd_id": 7,"cmd_name": "10 min (Tous réseau)","cmd_instruction": "*171*0100#","cmd_commentaire": "100 Unités pour 1 jour","opetor_id": 1,"mnu_id": 11,"test":1}]}
```

and another:

```
{"operator":[
{"opetor_id": 1,"opetor_name": "Airtel","ctry_id": "CD"},
{"opetor_id": 2,"opetor_name": "Vodacom","ctry_id": "CD"},
{"opetor_id": 3,"opetor_name": "Orange","ctry_id": "CD"},
{"opetor_id": 4,"opetor_name": "Tigo","ctry_id": "CD"}]}
```

I'm passing the data in RecyclerView once I verify that the `operator_id` from my two json file are the same this is my codes:

```java
String cmd_id = new String();
String cmd_name = new String();
String cmd_instruction = new String();
String cmd_commentaire = new String();
...
for (int z = 0; z < jArrayMenu.length(); z++)
{
    JSONObject MnuDetail = jArrayMenu.getJSONObject(z);
    Integer operatorIdMenu = MnuDetail.getInt("opetor_id");
    //cmd_operator_test.add(MnuDetail.getInt("opetor_id"));
    if (OperaID.equals(operatorIdMenu))
    {
        cmd_id=(MnuDetail.getString("cmd_id"));
        cmd_name=(MnuDetail.getString("cmd_name"));
        cmd_instruction=(MnuDetail.getString("cmd_instruction"));
        cmd_commentaire=(MnuDetail.getString("cmd_commentaire"));
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, cmd_id, cmd_name, cmd_instruction, cmd_commentaire);
        //set the Adapter to RecyclerView
        rv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
}
```

here is my adapter:

```java
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    String cmd_id = new String();
    String cmd_name = new String();
    String cmd_instruction = new String();
    String cmd_commentaire = new String();
    ArrayList<String> cmd_operator = new ArrayList<>();

    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String cmd_id, String cmd_name, String cmd_instruction, String cmd_commentaire) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cmd_id = cmd_id;
        this.cmd_name = cmd_name;
        this.cmd_instruction = cmd_instruction;
        this.cmd_commentaire = cmd_commentaire;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // inflate the item Layout
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v); // pass the view to View Holder
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // set the data in items
        //holder.name.setText(cmd_id.get(position));
        holder.email.setText(cmd_name);
        //holder.mobileNo.setText(cmd_instruction.get(position));
        // implement setOnClickListener event on item view.
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // display a toast with person name on item click
                //Toast.makeText(context, cmd_name.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please grant the permission to call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    requestPermissions();
                }else {
                    //Toast.makeText(orange.this, "Recycler View Item: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //final Intent myIntent;
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + cmd_instruction.replace("#","") + Uri.encode("#")));
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cmd_id.length();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name, email, mobileNo;// init the item view's

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // get the reference of item view's
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);
            mobileNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mobileNo);
        }
    }
}
```

when i run my app the place where the `opetor_id` equal 1 in the `ussd_code` json file it gives me only the last value orthers wise I have five `opetor_id` but still having the last value. Dont know why orthers are not appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are traversing through the loop and creating a new instance of custom adapter each time. So by the en dof the loop the last instance will only retain.

So, what you need to do is create a model which will contain variables cmd_id,cmd_name, cmd_instruction and cmd_commentaire. Then create an ArrayAdapter of type model.

When you traverse through the loop just add new model to that ArrayAdapter, do not create new instance of the adapter each time.

**UPDATE:**
Create a POJO of your JSON.

```
List<MyPojo> lstPojo = new ArrayList<~>;
for (int z = 0; z < jArrayMenu.length(); z++)
{
    JSONObject MnuDetail = jArrayMenu.getJSONObject(z);
    int operatorIdMenu = MnuDetail.getInt("opetor_id");
    //cmd_operator_test.add(MnuDetail.getInt("opetor_id"));
    if (OperaID == operatorIdMenu)
    {
        lstPojo.add(new MyPojo(MnuDetail.getString("cmd_id"),
                               MnuDetail.getString("cmd_name"),
                               MnuDetail.getString("cmd_instruction"),
                               MnuDetail.getString("cmd_commentaire")));
    }

}
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            lstPojo);
rv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see what you mean but please can you help me with a small codes so that i can have idea? Thanks.

Comment: @ArkaL Populate your adapter outside the for loop. It's better to make one pojo class and set data in it and pass pojo class list to your custom adapter.

Comment: @Piyush Thanks for your answer  but the only problem that i face now how can i then pass my json value in this class?

Comment: create a pojo of your JSON and pass the pojo as dataset

Comment: If `operatorIdMenu`  is integer then  `if (OperaID.equals(operatorIdMenu))` condition never execute. For int simply use  `OperaID==operatorIdMenu`

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee then my Adapter must change also right? 'cause i'm getting an error from here : `CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            lstPojo);
    rv.setAdapter(customAdapter);`

Comment: change the constructor of your CustomAdaptor. Add relative parameter as in `new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstPojo)`

Comment: @ArKaL happy to help :)